# How do I find the 2nd smallest value in a column only if they are in the top 50% of sales?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table in Excel that shows the % change of sales YOY by agent, I need to be able to quickly point out who has the 2nd smallest change but ONLY if they are in the top 50% of sales, I was able to use `=MINIFS` to find the smallest by saying `=MINIFS($A:$A,$B:$B,"<.5",$B:$B,">0` where `A` is the % change and `B` indicates % of sales. I can't seem to find a way to use this type of logic to find the 2nd or 3rd smallest, if `B<.5` what is the 2nd smallest amount in column `A`?

Answer (score 0):

Use AGGREGATE:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,7,A:A/((B:B<.5)*(B:B>0)),2)
```

This is using the SMALL formula, the last digit `2` is the `k` which means the rank you want, in this case the 2nd smallest.

This creates an array of numbers and errors, the numbers are the value of A:A where the criteria is met and the errors are divide by 0 errors where they are not met.

The AGGREAGATE ignores the errors and returns the 2nd lowest.

**A note by Jos Woolley about using full column range references in a natural array type formula**:

> It might be an idea to add a comment to your post to let readers know that your use of entire column references is only an example, and that they should be replaced with smaller ranges in practice. Not all users are aware that the use of entire column references is perfectly fine with MINIFS (which employs implicit detection of the last-used cell within the range passed) but not with AGGREGATE (which does not employ said implicit detection, and so is forced to process all 1,048,576 cells passed).

Comment: It might be an idea to add a comment to your post to let readers know that your use of entire column references is only an example, and that they should be replaced with smaller ranges in practice. Not all users are aware that the use of entire column references is perfectly fine with `MINIFS` (which employs implicit detection of the last-used cell within the range passed) but not with `AGGREGATE` (which does not employ said implicit detection, and so is forced to process all 1,048,576 cells passed).

Comment: @JosWoolley good idea.  You put it so well, I just copied it into the answer.  I also made it a community wiki as now you have provided a significant portion to the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, much appreciated.